# Emacs ActionScript indentation in function parameter list

Tags: actionscript, emacs

I am using the actionscript-mode by Austin Haas with Emacs 23.3.1. When I write a function in ActionScript with a lot of arguments, I like to split it into several lines. I would like it to look like

```
public function foo(bar:Bar,
                    baz:Baz,
                    qux:Qux):void {...}
```

But with the indentation of the actionscript-mode, it looks like

```
public function foo(bar:Bar,
    baz:Baz,
    qux:Qux):void {...}
```

This annoys me a lot. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What about function *calls* rather than definitions? Would you want to see similar behavior there too? What about multi-line arrays?

Comment: I guess i should have written that, but that wasn't of immediate annoyance. Yes, I would like the same behaviour there too.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer is: I don't see there's a good way to do it at all. Today indentation is based only on the previous line, and it is completely broken if E4X is used, or nested object literals or array literals and so on :(

Below is however, something that might help you out if you don't mind some handwork applied to each such instance you want to modify:

```
(defun as3-align-regex ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((align-to-tab-stop nil))
    (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end)
          "\\(\\s(\\|\\s-\\)\\(\\sw+\\)" 1 1 nil)))
```

Note that you need to select the region in a way that it starts with the first parenthesis, bracket or space and until the last term that you want to align. It's kind of ugly, but a good solution would require too much effort.

Comment: Okay. Well, that's too bad. But I your method out, and it kind of works. When I say kind of, it's because it screws up the indentation of the following lines somewhat. But it's okay! I can learn to live with that. Thank you so much!